# Undefined font: In Fpdf. If i set function __construct

Tags: php, class, constructor, fpdf

I'm working on an invoice to PDF. 
Only if I set a `Constructor` in the class the font will not find.

This is my class:

```
<?php require('fpdf.php');

class Invoice extends FPDF
{
    /**
     * Database
     *
     * @access private 
     */     
    private $db;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @access public 
     */   
    public function __construct() {             
        $this->db = new Database();             
    }
    //The rest of the code
}
?>
```

Also `parent::FPDF();` will not work in the constructor.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDF::FPDF().

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are extending from FPDF and if you are overriding constructor, you have to call parent constructor with expected signature.

You can define 'FPDF_FONTPATH' constant in bootstrap php.

FPDF has following constructor signature

```
function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4') 
{
  //line 106 to 117 has following font path initialization
  // Font path
  if(defined('FPDF_FONTPATH'))
  {
    $this->fontpath = FPDF_FONTPATH;
      if(substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='/' && substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='\\')
        $this->fontpath .= '/';
  }
  elseif(is_dir(dirname(__FILE__).'/font'))
    $this->fontpath = dirname(__FILE__).'/font/';
  else
    $this->fontpath = '';
  // Core fonts

...
}
```

Try something like below

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','change/to/fpdf/font/path');

class Invoice extends FPDF
{   
  private $db;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct('P', 'mm', 'A4');
    $this->db = new Database();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know. But i can not accept the answer. 


Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.